# cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<x>' to 'x'

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need to add some data in `OptionRoleTable:`

```
    public class OptionRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public int OptionsId { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual Options Options { get; set; }
}
```

and this is `Options  Tabel`:

```
  public partial class Options
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OptionName { get; set; }
    public string RouteFunctionName { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OptionRole> OptionRoles { get; set; }
}
```

i must check data not exist in `OptionRole` , when i using this code for add data in `OptionRole` :

```
  public async Task<Options> findOptionsId(int optionId)
    {
        return await _option.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == optionId);
    }

 public async Task<bool> AddorUpdateOptions(int optionId, IList<int> selectedRoleValue)
    {
        List<OptionVM> optionVMs = new List<OptionVM>();
        List<int> currentOptionValue = new List<int>();

        var optionRole = await findOptionsId(optionId);
        if (optionRole == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        foreach (var item in selectedRoleValue)
        {
            var findRole = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(item);
            var findOPR = optionRole.OptionRoles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OptionsId== optionId && x.RoleId==item);
            if (findOPR != null)
            {
                currentOptionValue.Add(item);
            }
        }

        if (selectedRoleValue == null)
        {
            selectedRoleValue = new List<int>();
        }

        var newOptionRole = selectedRoleValue.Except(currentOptionValue).ToList();
        foreach (var opRole in newOptionRole)
        {
            var findRole = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(opRole);
            if (findRole != null)
            {
                optionRole.OptionRoles.Add(new OptionRole
                {
                    OptionsId = optionRole.Id,
                    RoleId = findRole.Id
                });
            }
        }

        var removeOptionRole = currentOptionValue.Except(selectedRoleValue).ToList();
        foreach (var remove in removeOptionRole)
        {
            var findOptionRole = _optionRoles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == remove);
            if (findOptionRole != null)
            {
                optionRole.OptionRoles.Remove(findOptionRole);
            }
        }

        return  Update(optionRole.OptionRoles);

    }
```

I must have pass a class type of `Options`  when i using this code . it show me this Error :

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' to 'StoreFinal.Entities.Entities.Identity.OptionRole'    StoreFinal.Services C:\Users\Mr-Programer\Desktop\New folder\StoreFinal\StoreFinal.Services\Contracts\Identity\Service\ApplicationOptionRoleManager.cs  97  Active

Error in this line : `return  Update(optionRole.OptionRoles);`

whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?

**Edit :**

Update Method :

```
   public virtual bool Update(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            Entities.Attach(entity);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you highlight the line where exception error happens?

Comment: this line `return  Update(optionRole.OptionRoles);`

Comment: Can you show the Signature of Update Method?

Comment: i edit the question

Comment: See my answer, I am not claiming this is what you need. But this may point you to right direction.

Comment: The Update method expects a single object whereas your code passes a Collection.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Update Method signature:

```
public virtual bool Update(T entity);
```

It accepts a param type T which should be One Entity - Why One Entity -- because Entities.Attach() accepts only 1 Object. While what you are passing to it is:

```
return  Update(optionRole.OptionRoles);
```

Where OptionRoles is of type: ICollection<OptionRole>  --

For understandings sake, Change it to

```
return  Update(optionRole.OptionRoles[0]);
```

or

```
return  Update(optionRole.OptionRoles.First());
```

And then share the result.

Comment: it not show me error but i can test it for insert data . beacuse it in this line exit the breakpoint `var findOPR = optionRole.OptionRoles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.OptionsId== optionId && x.RoleId==item);`